# Adding File Name to a list of dataframes

Tags: r, list

I have a list of several dataframes and would like to add a new variable based on the file name. I'm not sure how to do this other than splitting the list into individual dataframes, manually adding the variable, and then merging them all back into on large dataframe. This seems highly inefficient to me and was wondering if there's a more efficient way to do it by directly extracting the file name.

I don't know how to add a good example of the list of dataframes. The file names are state names. After using do.call() to create one df, the first 300 obs are from Ohio, the next 150 from Alaska, 364 from New Jersey, and finally 85 from Vermont.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You have to add example of this list; what variable?; what's file name?

Comment: Do you want to change individual elements of a list of dataframes? Is it you make these changes while creating the list? Have you tried `lapply` or similar functions?